# Hyperlink to pick .oft file dynamically

Tags: html, hyperlink, outlook

We have a set of users who have an outlook template (with same name) stored in their machines.
I want to create a hyperlink clicking on which will open that .oft file from their machine and they can use it further. Basically I need to know whether by using any script, we can get the location/machine name or not.
Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Environment variables provide this type of information.

http://www.slipstick.com/developer/windows-environment-variables-outlook-macros/

```
Sub EnumSEVars()
      Dim strVar As String
      Dim i As Long
      For i = 1 To 255
          strVar = Environ$(i)
          If LenB(strVar) = 0& Then Exit For
          Debug.Print strVar
      Next
  End Sub
```

http://www.askvg.com/list-of-environment-variables-in-windows-xp-vista-and-7/

http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html